# Disabling aspxgridviews on server-side, how to handle on client-side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've just started a project where our BA guy needs me to disable all of our aspxgridviews past a certain time.

```
C#
     public void CutoffDateTime()
      {
          //DateTime today = DateTime.Now; // this will be for live code
          DateTime today = new DateTime(2016, 4, 15, 7, 00, 00); // for testing
          DateTime cutoff = new DateTime(2016, 4, 19, 7, 00, 00);

          if (today >= cutoff.AddDays(7))
          {
              cutoff = cutoff.AddDays(7);
          }
          // if today is past cutoff, disable all grids
          if (today < cutoff.AddHours(-55))
          {
              gvProduction.Enabled = false;
              gvProductionSummary.Enabled = false;
              gvDowntimeSummary.Enabled = false;
              gvNonProd.Enabled = false;
              cbCutoff.Checked = false;
          }
          else
              cbCutoff.Checked = true;
    }
```

The grids are disabled correctly, but this affects some client-side code that calls the grid.Refresh() methods.

I've added the checkbox as an invisible control so that I can easily interface with the client-side and I'm trying to add:

```
JS
    if (cbCutoff.GetChecked()==true)
        grid.Refresh();
```

But I am still getting JavaScript runtime errors stating that 'cbCutoff is undefined' but I can't think of another way to accomplish this task.

Thanks

**EDIT**:

Here is part of my asp.net markup that I'm trying to fix via DexExpress' GetChecked() method that returns true if checked:

aspx

```
<ClientSideEvents ActiveTabChanged="function(s, e) {
    if (e.tab.index.toString() ==  1 && cbCutoff.GetChecked()==true)
        gridProductionSummary.Refresh();
}" />
```

Comment: Can you post the `ASPX` markup for your page?

Comment: Can you just set the visibility of the GridView to "False"? `gvProduction.Visible = false;` The control will render, and it will be passed to the client, but it won't be displayed. Unless you don't want that data present in the client interface at all.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. In ASP.Net, you need to pass the ID of the control in JS, but it is not the ID you type into the control because it gets rendered by the server as something different. In your JS code, you need to do something like this <%= cbCutoff.ClientID %> which will populate the actual ID field found on the rendered page.

Comment: The ClientInstanceName is also set to 'cbCutoff'. I will look into using <% %> tag. I just made an edit to include one of the functions that I'm trying to fix.

Comment: Basically, I'm just trying to edit the existing functions with an if-statement to check the state of my checkbox 'cbCutoff'

Comment: The easiest way is `if(cbCutoff && cbCutoff.GetChecked()) grid.Refresh();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using

```
    if (cb.GetChecked())
grid.Refresh();
```

and set the checkbox to enabled on server-side